# Can Java versions between server and client cause issues when dealing with sockets?

Tags: java, sockets

I have built a program that will perform some synchronization (parallel or interleaved), and I am seeing some funky issues which I think are related to java sockets.

What I am wondering is, if my server has different version(s) of java than my client, can that cause any problems. Problems such as a message not being sent through the socket?

Right now my server has multiple versions (32 bit and 64 bit), while my client has just one version (only 32bit). Could this seriously cause a problem where a socket could die or not send something through?

Please let me know if I am not descriptive enough, I will try to add more if I am being confusing.

Edit:

I am using all windows machines. However the server could be either win7 or win8. All clients are win8. This is how I'm sending information over my socket

```
protected PrintWriter out;
out = new PrintWriter(infoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println("success");
out.flush();
```

Comment: Socket by itself says nothing and is most likely not the problem. Different JRE's can however produce different results in some cases, e.g. the Order of elements in a non-ordered collection can vary, API's that return an interface type may return a different implementation of the type and so on. So its more likely the data you're sending over the socket is the issue.

Comment: I have updated my question with what I am sending. The "success" is never received on the client in some cases...but not all

Comment: Thats already a possible culprit, since new PrintWriter(stream) uses the platform character encoding. To be safe, always explicitly specify the encoding when you have control, don't leave it to chance. Also, how are you *receiving* the data on the other end? You have multiple chances to mess this up: Encoding by the sender, receiver and also, generally inappropiate encoding (if for example transmitting an ä, US-ASCII will not do).

Comment: What do you suggest I use instead of printwriter? Even the java tutorials use this

Comment: You can use PrintWriter, no problem The problem is the constructor flavor you chose, switch to (e.g.)  `new PrintWriter(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` - this one explicitly specifies the encoding to use. And also at the receiving end, make sure to specify UTF_8 as well. But since you cite the string "success\n" not being received - I suspect the problem may be caused by the way you receive it - you need to take care not to attempt to read more data than is actually sent; otherwise you may get stuck in a blocking read on the stream.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't think so.  A socket is standard low level network interface.  It doesn't even care about the OS.

To verify, you might try running both client and server on the same machine, with the two different VM's versions.  What might be a more likely problem are the differences on the machines (such as character encoding) or a general bug in the software.

Comment: oddly enough...i don't see any issue when both machines have the same 32 bit java version on them. When I use java 7u60 ONLY there is no issue. I'm just not sure if this is coincidence or real

Comment: can you elaborate on the character encoding?

Comment: I've had general issues before with a client server sending different character encodings to each other, particularly if a database or files are involved.  There are a couple places this is set, at the OS level, file level and database level.  If it's a linux server, the LANG and NLS_LANG environment variables might be an issue, for example.

Comment: I am using all windows machines. However the server could be either win7 or win8. All clients are win8.

Comment: I might avoid using Windows 8 as a server... it's still a bit experimental.   For a test, I might  try some alternate sample code as well, like: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html

Comment: Unfortunately I can't avoid using windows 8. Some of our work machines have them....but I completely agree with you. I can't stand win8.