# Having issues with .jar file, but not when ran inside my IDE (Netbeans)

Tags: java, sockets, netbeans

Ok so here's the thing. I posted a question the other day [Can Java versions between server and client cause issues when dealing with sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817114/can-java-versions-between-server-and-client-cause-issues-when-dealing-with-socke)

and since then I have done more debugging. I said in the question above:

"have built a program that will perform some synchronization (parallel or interleaved), and I am seeing some funky issues which I think are related to java sockets."

Since then, I have found something out, when I run my .jar file that is built by NetBeans, I see the issue where a message is not recieved on my client from the server.

Now, oddly enough, if I use Netbeans to run the program, no messages are missed and everything works as expected.

My client machine is using:  32bit Java 7 Update 60

While my server has: Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 75, Java 8 Update 45, Java 8 Update 45 (64 bit)

My Java Platform in NetBeans is: JDK 1.7

In fact, the server could have different java versions even, but this is what I have on my development machine. The Client will ALWAY have Java 7 Update 60.

Anyway, what could be causing my program to not work as expected outside of netbeans? Could it be my Java Platform? Is there something I should be doing for Java 8 that I am not doing when building my .jar?

If any more information is needed just as and I will provide by editing my question.

I am in dire need of fixing this.

Comment: There are some changes in security with Java 8 where sockets are concerned - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999387  (Search for 'socket' on that page to find the relevant section).

Comment: " Applications using datagram sockets or server tcp sockets (and a security manager) may encounter security exceptions where none were seen before. If this occurs, users should review whether the port number being requested is expected, and if this is the case, a socket permission grant can be added to the local security policy, to resolve the issue." - this could be a good place to look.

Comment: I will look into this...but why would I not have problems when running my program with NetBeans, then have problems outside of NetBeans?

Comment: What JDK is currently configured as the default in Netbeans? If it is set to use JDK 7 and Windows default JRE is 8, it would explain the inconsistency.

Comment: I assume the windows default is java 8....and yes netbeans jdk 7 is used. Updating to jdk 8, and re-building my project. I will update after that. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Bear in mind that if there is an issue with security policy settings on sockets in JDK 8, the problem will still be there, and changing your code to work correctly with JDK 8 will prevent it running on older versions. A possible option is to install JRE 7 on Windows and set that to default. Unless you are specifically leveraging JDK 8 functionality, sticking with JDK 7 might be a better solution.

Comment: Unfortunately these are work machines being used as a server and I doubt we can set a default version. I will look into it.

Comment: If you have another JDK installed, you can use the java.exe from its directory called with a fully qualified path without needing to set a default. Just call c:\path_to_jdk7\bin\java -jar myjar. You might need to add your libs directory to the path before running the JRE, but this could be done easily in a launch script.